# Why put images into Next.js public folder? Is there an advantage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel, static-files

I could put my images anywhere it seems, and it just works fine. However, Next.JS seems to recommend to put the images into the `public` folder. What's the advantage here?

Answer (score 2):

If you have your static files in the `public` folder, it would be easier to import them elsewhere. Files inside `public` can be referenced by your code starting from the base URL (`/`).

For example, if you add an image to `public/me.png`, the following code will access the image:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

function Avatar() {
  return <Image src="/me.png" alt="me" width="64" height="64" />
}

export default Avatar
```

More info about that can be found here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

Comment: Thank you. But is this literally it? There is no other advantage to having them there other than that it's easier to reference them like this?

Comment: @antonwilhelm The files inside of `public` can also be accessed from the base URL. Like you want to only see a specific static file, maybe `me.png` which was under the `public` folder, you can, by going to `mywebsite.com/me.png`.
That's why the `public` folder is useful for `robots.txt`, `favicon.ico` files. You can also have `.html` files into it.
Other than that, there's no advantage.

Comment: There's not a specific advantage to `/public` over a different directory name - that's just the convention that Next.js has chosen.